# Automatic login of User without entering credentials (LtpaToken)

Tags: single-sign-on, lotus-domino, isapi, ltpa

**What I am trying to achieve:**

Automatically login a user by creating a LtpaToken (No user id, password)

Before the request comes to Domino server, the user will be already authenticated with an external system which adds a http header variable called USERID.

**What I have done so far**

I wrote a DSAPI filter. In the "kFilterRawRequest" event I generate the LtpaToken and using the SetHeader method, I write it to the header.

I can't figure out what next. If I need to redirect to a page afterwards, do I set the Location http header variable? Do I need to handle the "kFilterAuthenticate" event at all? I see that this event fires after user enter credentials, so may be not the event I want. But the documentation says this is where to customize authentication.

DSAPI works similar to ISAPI, so I tagged ISAPI too. Any guidance is much appreciated.